# NLP - Sentence reconstruction

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, transformer

I need to define a neural network for sentence reconstruction. Below the details:
The dataset is composed by a snapshot of wikipedia. We restricted the vocabolary to the 10K most frequent words, and only took sentences making use of this vocabulary. In addition, we restricted to sequences with a length between 3 and 30 words.
Here an example:
For instance, given the sequence of words

> > > to henry at be first france the king wanted with of friends

the model should be able to reconstruct the following sentence

> > > at first henry wanted to be friends with the king of france

Concerning the score:
Let s be the source string and p your prediction. The quality of the results will be measured according to the following metric:

look for the longest substring w between s and p
compute |w|/|s|
If the match is exact, the score is 1.

When computing the score, you should NON consider the start and end tokens.

The longest common substring can be computed with the SequenceMatcher function of difflib, that allows a simple definition of our metric.

The score must be computed as an average of at least 3K random examples taken form the test set.